# setAttribute behavior on HTML content, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Initially I have the following

```
<a id="myLink" href="#amazinglinktonowhere">My initial link</a>
```

After I load my webpage, I'm able to get the attribute `href` and text value to change and update the link to point to Google with new text `"It's not the same text anymore"` and if I click on it, I'm redirected to the Google page. So probably everything works. But if you check my HTML source code, the link still remains the same.

Why? How can I change it? Is it the normal behavior of `setAttribute`? And even when I change the content with `link.innerHTML = 'blabla'`

**My Code:**

```js
var link = document.getElementById('myLink');
link.innerHTML = "It's not the same text anymore";
var href = link.getAttribute('href');

link.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.fr/');
```

```html
<a id="myLink" href="#amazinglinktonowhere">My initial link</a>
```

Comment: Because "View Source" in Chrome (for example) shows content that arrived to the browser. Use "Developer Tools" or "Inspect Element" menu item to inspect the current DOM.

Comment: And you have two body tags, you know...

Comment: @Rushikumar Copy paste result ! Igor Ok I see, View source have is limit to work on dynamical html content. Thanks to you (and thanks for re-writing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46900339/2990144), View Source only shows you *source code*. That is, it shows you the code as you originally wrote it (or at least, how the server sent it, and generally servers send it as-is).

In your case, you are using JavaScript to *update* the page as it is running. Your source code remains unchanged. The page itself has its own state, which can be manipulated to your heart's desire. We need to update the state of the page to do all sorts of fancy things, like animations, dropdown menus, play videos, and other interactive features. None of these things change your original code, and by association, they won't change what you see via View Source.

If you want to see the result of your code changing the page in realtime, you should instead use the Inspector / Elements pane in your browser.

- [Firefox Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector)
- [Chrome Elements](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-dom)